Tribromine octoxide solubility in water
As Wikipedia indicates some properties of tribromine octoxide as followed:

The compound forms a white solid. It exists in two forms which are both soluble in water. It is unstable above -73 °C.

If the compound is unstable at such low temperature, how could they figure out the solubility while water is in solid state?

My guess would be pressure.

I am trying to imagine putting two solids together, then increasing the pressure to melt them?

There's unstable and unstable. Decomposition doesn't have to be faster than dissolving.

Agree, but I desire to understand the process though.

Since it is a free radical, it decomposes at those temperature. But I am still curious on how the solubility was measured. I am also curious on the "two forms". Everywhere I see the same structure, I have not seen the "other form". Food for another question?
